# Conditional pattern matching

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to find the files that contain a string and this string must not be in the comment section. For example:
string to match = 'Map'

1. /* aoeuaeu Map    */
2. // Map aoeuoeu
3. uoeu = Map + 2

grep should only match 3.

I tried:

```
grep -r --include=*.mc "^.*[^\/][^\*].*\sMap"
```

**EDIT**
the cases I posted are references, I mean the string *Map* is used in a cpp code

Comment: Will comments always be on one line?  Or can comments with /* */ span multiple lines as they may in a source code file?  Are the numbers here going to be in the file or are just illustrative for the question?

Comment: the comments can be longer than one line and the examples are just illustrative

Comment: Can you have strings? How would a string containing `/* ... */` be represented? If you parse a construct `/* " */ "` are you now inside a comment or a string? If you have `Map` inside a string should it be matched or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this post as a reference,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code

Use the preprocessor to remove comments from your source file, then pipe it to grep for the pattern that you are looking for.

```
sh-4.3$ cat source.c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 * aoeuaeu Map                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 */                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

// Map aoeuoeu                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

uoeu = Map + 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
aeiou Int; // Map                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

sh-4.3$ gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E source.c | grep -v ^# | grep Map                                                                                                                                                                                     
uoeu = Map + 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

sh-4.3$
```

You may not need the `grep -v ^#`.  I included it here just to exclude the comment line that is output when you run the file through the preprocessor.

Comment: cool! c-preprocessor is a good idea+1

Answer (score 0):

The version bellow cover the general simple cases

```
perl -n0E 's!//.*!!g; 
           s!/\*.*?\*/!!gs; 
           say $ARGV if /Mat/'   *.c *.md
```

As pointed by @MikeA (please see his solution) some situation need C-preprocessor or even cpp-parser Example nested comments, Comments in strings.

To serach all `.md` in your project tree (assuming simple names...)

```
perl ....  $(find -name="*.md")
```